# Azure blob file concurrent write

Tags: c#, azure, concurrency, azure-functions, blob

I am new to azure. I want to achieve the below , please help me with some source code

I have an HTTP Azure function that will write the running number(sequence no) to the blob file(Overwrite). Means, each call the count will increase by one. I have a console app , from the **multiple threads** will call this Azure function.

How do I achieve this with thread-safe, without duplicating running number to write to the blob file?

***output***

thread1 --> blobfile will be updated by 1

thread2 --> blobfile will be updated by 2

--

--

--

thread**N** --> blobfile will be updated by **N**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/concurrency-manage?tabs=dotnet

Comment: This seems like a iffy solution though. I mean, why not use cosmos, or any other technology that supports concurrency and more idiomatic usage, why are you storing such trivial information in a blob file?

Comment: @TheGeneral I tried with Mutex to increment counter [link]https://www.chubbydeveloper.com/csharp-mutex/ [/link] but I am getting duplicates if I use many threads. the same program without using azure function instead use normal function get the correct result. can you guide me

Comment: A Mutex is not going to help you in an environment that can potentially have your service run in separate data centers, and especially if you are using a consumption plan. Read the link i gave you to identify the way to use a blob with various types of concurrency support. Maybe someone has time to help you with the code.. good luck :)

Comment: oh ok. What is your suggestion for the best approach. Is writing to the blob will solve this or any other better approach

Comment: You can use the distributed locking for ex - check [this](https://redis.io/topics/distlock). However, you need to make sure that the value always reflects the correct value instead of last man win scenario.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the content of the blob is a single incrementing counter? Or does each thread set the value of the counter. If so, given your example if thread2 finishes earlier than thread1, what value do you expect? Is there also just one process (console app instance) writing these values?

Comment: @PeterBons its a single incrementing counter. The thread may work differently as you said. its possible that Thread2 or Thread10 can be the last one to complete. 

**Original Requirement** is Azure function return unique incremental sequence number. for example if I have 1000 threads all the sequence number shd be different.

Comment: @leo see my answer at your other question regarding having this using only an azure function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69954638/azure-function-return-unique-sequence-number/70001043#70001043

Comment: @leo if you really want to use blob you should take a lease as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/concurrency-manage?tabs=dotnet#pessimistic-concurrency-for-blobs), update the counter and let go of the lease. Other writers should wait until they have taken a lease.

Comment: @PeterBons I tried similar kind of approach [link]https://github.com/0x414c49/AzureAutoNumber but the response is bit slower

Comment: Could you define *bit slower*? Are we talking in seconds, milliseconds?

Comment: @PeterBons I tried using AutoNumber nuget package it can generate around 20 numbers in 1sec. I also tried with durable entity and orchestrator but generation take more than 1 sec for a number addition. I am trying get bit more faster than the current result. is it possible?